# Javalin with JPMS and ServiceLoader results in NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/NoWhenBranchMatchedException

Tags: java, kotlin, java-platform-module-system, serviceloader, javalin

Running Javalin with JPMS and ServiceLoader leads to a `NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/NoWhenBranchMatchedException`. The same code following two other approaches works fine, though (see at the end of this post for details):

- No JPMS and ServiceLoader: if I run the very same Javalin application not as a JPMS module and without the ServiceLoader to resolve dependencies, then everything works just fine.
- Console app: I can also run a console application which is a real JPMS module and uses the ServiceLoader to resolve dependencies.

### Steps to reproduce the issue

**(1)** Clone [main](https://github.com/baumgarb/javalin-with-jpms/tree/main) branch

**(2)** Try to run API in root folder of project

```
# Windows
.\gradlew.bat :api:run

# Linux
./gradlew :api:run
```

You should see the following error:

```
> Task :api:run FAILED
[main] INFO org.example.api.WebAPI - Hello World from WebAPI, yay :-)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/NoWhenBranchMatchedException
        at io.javalin@4.6.4/io.javalin.core.JavalinConfig$Inner.<init>(JavalinConfig.java:77)
        at io.javalin@4.6.4/io.javalin.core.JavalinConfig.<init>(JavalinConfig.java:67)
        at io.javalin@4.6.4/io.javalin.Javalin.<init>(Javalin.java:54)
        at io.javalin@4.6.4/io.javalin.Javalin.create(Javalin.java:91)
        at io.javalin@4.6.4/io.javalin.Javalin.create(Javalin.java:78)
        at org.example.api/org.example.api.WebAPI.main(WebAPI.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.NoWhenBranchMatchedException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 6 more
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

---

### The following two approaches work fine, though:

**(3)** No JPMS and ServiceLoader: change to branch [no-jpms-and-serviceloader](https://github.com/baumgarb/javalin-with-jpms/tree/no-jpms-and-serviceloader) and then you can successfully run the API via

```
# Windows
.\gradlew.bat :api:run

# Linux
./gradlew :api:run
```

**(4)** Console app: run it as a console application in either of the branches

```
# Windows
.\gradlew.bat :client:run

# Linux
./gradlew :client:run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a Javalin [GitHub issue](https://github.com/javalin/javalin/issues/1624) describing the same issue. It's solved by now, but for convenience reasons I'll drop the solution here on Stackoverflow as well.

Adding the following line to the module descriptor (`module-info.java`) of the `api` project solves the issue:

```
    requires io.javalin;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires org.slf4j.simple;
    requires kotlin.stdlib;                        <-- simply add this line here

    uses org.example.services.api.PersonReader;
```

The root cause seems to be that Javalin is not modularized yet. If you look closer into the module resolution (pass `--show-module-resolution` arg to java) you will see that Javalin is treated as an automatic module and the auto-generated requires statements for this automatic module do not include `kotlin.stdlib`.

If Javalin ever becomes modularized this should no longer be an issue. Until then, this is a viable solution which can also be applied to other not-yet-modularized projects.